# How to delay $mainframe->redirect("/index.html") in a form submission until $mapping is processed?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a form by RSForms in Joomla 4, and using $mappings to map submission field values in another table; however, I am using

```
$mainframe->redirect("/index.html");
```

to redirect user to index upon form submission, which breaks $mapping to work.
If I removed the above code the mapping is done perfectly and the same page is reloaded; however, I want to redirect the user to another page, but only without breaking the mapping.

Is there a way to only execute the redirect after form submission is full finished (thus ensure mapping is done)?
Alternatively, can I use another redirect function to achieve the same target?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use

```
//run mapping from RSForm
RSFormProHelper::doMappings($mappings, array('replace' => $replace, 'with' => $with));

//stop redirect until process finish
$mainframe->redirect("/index.html",false);
```

Good luck